# How to search SIMBAD using identifiers?

Tags: the-moon, spectroscopy, data-analysis, raw-data

I'm trying to get some data about the moon from [SIMBAD](http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-fid) (specifically, radiation spectrum in certain wavelengths), and I encountered an unexpected problem: I can't find the Moon.

In SIMBAD, I can search using several different methods. Since I'm looking for a specific object in the sky, I thought the best method would be just to search for the moon by its name, using "Query by identifiers".

It may sound silly, but the problem is I don't know what is the nomenclature of the moon, nor how to find it. Using the obvious guesses ("Moon", "Luna", etc.) gave me nothing. What am I missing here? Does identifier mean something else than what I thought?

P.S. This problem also occurred to me while searching for the Sun, which signals to me that I'm probably missing something critical here...

Comment: You don’t really need Simbad for this - your best bet is probably searching [NASA ADS](https://ui.adsabs.harvard.edu) for “moon” or “lunar” along with other relevant keywords.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you look on the [main SIMBAD page](http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/), you will see the following in the box titled "Content":

> The SIMBAD astronomical database provides basic data, cross-identifications, bibliography and measurements for astronomical objects **outside the solar system**.

(emphasis mine)

The Moon and the Sun are inside the Solar System, thus they are out-of-scope for SIMBAD.

Comment: Ok, I feel pretty silly right now. Thanks!